# Dereference ... may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Tags: java

Есть следующий код:

```
TerminalsTypes terminalType = TerminalsTypes.valueOf(terminalTypeId) != null
                ? TerminalsTypes.valueOf(terminalTypeId)
                : TerminalsTypes.SPR;
switch (terminalType) {
    ...
}
```

И при этом *Intellij Idea* подсвечивает `terminalType` внутри `switch` и при наведении мышки выдаёт следующее сообщение:

> Dereference of 'terminalType' may produce
>   'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Почему это сообщение выводится несмотря на то, что при инициализации `terminalType` очевидно, что его значение быть `null` не может?

**UPD**

Код метода `TerminalsTypes.valueOf`:

```
public enum TerminalsTypes {
   ...
   public static TerminalsTypes valueOf(int type) {
        switch (type) {
            case 0:
                return SPR;
            ...
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
   ...
}
```

Comment: а что если у вас первый вызов выдает не null, а второй вызов такого же выдает null?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, я добавила в пост код метода `TerminalsTypes.valueOf`. И в моём случае это вроде как невозможно)

Comment: чтобы понять это нужен тот кто понимает код, а IDE это делает не очень хорошо.

Comment: попробуй сохранить `TerminalsTypes.valueOf(terminalTypeId)` в переменную и использовать именно ее в сравнении

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо за идею!!! Произошло чудо :) 
`TerminalsTypes terminalType = TerminalsTypes.valueOf(terminalTypeId);
        terminalType = terminalType != null
                ? terminalType
                : TerminalsTypes.INF;`
уже не выдаёт сообщения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Среда действует довольно логично: `TerminalsTypes.valueOf(terminalTypeId)` **может** вернуть `null`.

В коде есть две ветки, в одной из которых `TerminalsTypes.valueOf(terminalTypeId)`, которая может вернуть null, поэтому логичное предупреждение, что при использовании результата может быть исключение.

Решением может быть сохранение результата вызова `TerminalsTypes.valueOf(terminalTypeId)` в локальную переменную, которая уже будет использоваться в проверке:

```
TerminalsTypes terminalTypeValue = TerminalsTypes.valueOf(terminalTypeId)
TerminalsTypes terminalType = terminalTypeValue != null
                ? terminalTypeValue
                : TerminalsTypes.SPR;
switch (terminalType) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Совершенно не очевидно. Например такой вариант

```
class TerminalsTypes {
    public static TerminalsTypes valueOf(int terminalTypeId) {
        return Math.random() > 0.5 ? new TerminalsTypes() : null;
    }
}
```

Будет выдавать разное при разных вызовах

Чтобы избежать этого можно добавить такой код

```
TerminalsTypes terminalType = TerminalsTypes.valueOf(terminalTypeId);
if(terminalType == null) {
    terminalType = TerminalsTypes.SPR;
}
```

Или такой

```
TerminalsTypes terminalType = TerminalsTypes.valueOf(terminalTypeId);
terminalType = terminalType == null ? TerminalsTypes.SPR : terminalType;
```

Comment: Да, но у меня ведь рандомные значения в методе `TerminalsTypes.valueOf` не генерируются, это стандартный метод перечисления.

Comment: и как машина может это понять?